# How to do statement in a statement in react?

Tags: reactjs

I need to do a statement and print if the array is not empty, and if it's empty print an error message.

```
    {isEmpty(this.props.items) ? errorMessage : working}
```

The simple idea is to replace working to:

```js
{this.props.items && this.props.items.map((movie) => (
    <Link to={`/movie/${movie.id}`} key={movie.id}>
        <img className="Image-movie"
           src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movie.poster_path}`} 
           alt={`${movie.title}`}/>
    </Link>
))}
```

I try it to insert it but tells something about code syntax, any idea?

Comment: please post the error you are getting !

Comment: I don't have time do get into detail, but look into the `.map` alternative `.filter`. You can pull out just the empty ones with no need for another conditional statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many solutions is to asign the second statement to a `const`

```
const items = this.props.items ? this.props.items.map((movie) => (
    <Link to={`/movie/${movie.id}`} key={movie.id}>
        <img className="Image-movie"
           src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movie.poster_path}`} 
           alt={`${movie.title}`}/>
    </Link>
)) : null

return {isEmpty(this.props.items) ? errorMessage : items}
```

Since the first check is not necessary you could just do

```
return !this.props.items.length ? error : this.props.items.map(/*...*/)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that,

```
const {items} = this.props;
{items.length > 0  ? items.map((movie) => (
    <Link to={`/movie/${movie.id}`} key={movie.id}>
        <img className="Image-movie"
           src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movie.poster_path}`} 
           alt={`${movie.title}`}/>
    </Link>
)): (<Spinner /> || null) }
```

Comment: what is <Spinner/>?

Comment: it's a component you build to enhance the UX, 
so when the data isn't available yet, you show Loading circle or ...Loading text,

Comment: can you send me npm link package, please? Is a very useful tool

Comment: @Jonathan
I'm using a pure CSS spinner and it's very easy to do. However, there're  plenty of spinners out there, try this out https://www.react-spinners.com/, 

if you wanna know how to implement it with CSS I'll provide you with some examples.

Answer (score 0):

why you are  checking  again for `props.items`:

```
 const renderItems = this.props.items.map((movie) => (
        <Link to={`/movie/${movie.id}`} key={movie.id}>
            <img className="Image-movie"
               src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movie.poster_path}`} 
               alt={`${movie.title}`}/>
        </Link>
    ))



 {isEmpty(this.props.items) ? errorMessage : renderItems}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{this.props.items.length>0? this.props.items.map((movie) => (
<Link to={`/movie/${movie.id}`} key={movie.id}>
    <img className="Image-movie"
       src={sourcePath} 
       alt={movie.title}/>
</Link>)): errorMessage}
```